# ASP.NET: Can GridView be used to create a hierarchy?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, web-controls

We are using the GridView controls in some pages of our project which we dont want to change drastically, would it be possible to create a hierarchy in a gridview? Can this be achieved by using a GridView inside a Gridview to get the parent - child relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can nest GridViews inside one another. See the following article.

[Nesting GridViews](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/vb/article.php/c12647)

Answer (score 5):

yes you can, and it's quite easy...

the best approach is to have some ObjectDataSource's in order to the entire process be easier for you, or off course, you can bind the nasted gridview in the paraent gridview OnRowDataBound event, it is all up to you :)

example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvGrandFather" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsGrandFather">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="myField1" HeaderText="myText1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="myField2" HeaderText="myText2" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="myField3" HeaderText="myText3" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvFather" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsFather">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="myField1" HeaderText="myText1" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="myField2" HeaderText="myText2" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="myField3" HeaderText="myText3" />
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:GridView ID="gvSon" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsSon">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="myField1" HeaderText="myText1" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="myField2" HeaderText="myText2" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="myField3" HeaderText="myText3" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsGrandFather" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="Company" TypeName="CompanyDAO" SelectMethod="FindAll" />
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsFather" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="Employees" TypeName="EmployeesDAO" SelectMethod="FindByID">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="myFieldInCompanyObject" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsSon" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="Person"TypeName="PersonsDAO" SelectMethod="FindByID">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="myFieldInEmployeesObject" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

imagine that you have your Company object like

```
Company
  Field1
  Field2
  Field3
  Employees witch is List<Person>
    Field1
    Field2
    Field3
    Person  witch is List<Person>
      Field1
      Field2
      Field3
```

All you need to do is the DAO for each and return the list or the object itself like

```
public class CompanyDAO
{
    private List<Company> Companies
    {
        get
        {
            List<Company> companies = HttpContext.Current.Session["Companies"] as List<Company>;
            if (companies == null)
                companies = new List<Company>();
            return companies;
        }
    }
    public CompanyDAO() { }

    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    public IEnumerable<Company> FindAll()
    {
        return this.Companies;
    }

    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    public IEnumerable<Company> FindByID(String CompanyID)
    {
        return (from c in this.Companies where c.ID == CompanyID select c).ToList();
    }
}
```

hope it helps see the light at the end of the tunnel ;)

Comment: Will this implementation get the child row under the parent row? I dont want the child grid in the same row as the parent, but under the parent row.

Comment: if you want under, you need to use a ListView, there is a great article here: http://tinyurl.com/7yzby2

Answer (score 0):

Check out Telerik, their RadGrid has this kind of stuff out of the box (NestedHierarchy and detailtables)

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/Grid/Examples/Overview/DefaultCS.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Good articles on this 
[here](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/2008/02/Building-a-grouping-Grid-with-GridView-and-ASPNET-AJAX-toolkit-CollapsiblePanel.aspx)
which uses ASP.NET AJAX and the AJAX Control Toolkit to make it collapsible.

Answer (score -1):

GridView's are quite static.  We use XSLT if the tables are going to be more complex so we have ultimate control over it.  Otherwise Microsoft provide other ASP.NET controls such as the DataRepeater.